# How can I reload a jQuery dialog box from within the dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I load a page within a jQuery `Dialog`. After an ajax command is completed, I would like to be able to reload the same page within the jQuery `Dialog`. How can I reload a jQuery `Dialog` from within the page that is loaded in the `Dialog`?

Parent Page (Blah.aspx):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function view_dialog() {
        $('#dialog').load('blah2.aspx').dialog({
            title: 'test' ,
            modal: 'true',
            width: '80%',
            height: '740',
            position: 'center',
            show: 'scale',
            hide: 'scale',
            cache: false });
    }
</script>

<asp:Content
    ID="Content2"
    ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"
    runat="server">

    <input id="Button1" onclick="view_dialog()" type="button" value="button" />
    <div id="dialog" style="display: none"></div>

</asp:Content>
```

Dialog contents page (blah2.aspx):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function doit() {
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "someurl",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {
                    a: 'somevalue'
                }
            });

            request.done(function () {
            //refresh the current dialog by calling blah2.aspx again
        });
    }       
</script>

<asp:Content
    ID="Content2"
    ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"
    runat="server">

    <input id="Button1" onclick="doit()" type="button" value="button" />

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 14):

You are loading content from another page into the dialog container in the current page, so there is really only one page in play here. I would recommend only loading partial html (no `<head>` or `<body>` tags) from your dialog source page.

So you can either destroy the dialog and recreate it to reload the dialog content:

```
function reload_dialog()
{
    $('#dialog').dialog('destroy');
    view_dialog();
}

function view_dialog() {
    $('#dialog').load('blah2.aspx').dialog({
        title: 'test' ,
        modal: 'true',
        width: '80%',
        height: '740',
        position: 'center',
        show: 'scale',
        hide: 'scale',
        cache: false });
}
```

Or, you can reload the entire page.

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I know it's over 4 years later, but your code helped me out immensely!

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the ui.dialog in jQuery like this:

`$.ui.dialog.prototype.options.url; // Define a new option 'url'`

Now, you can replace the entire dialog "create" so it loads the url automatically and define the new "refresh" option:

```
    // Replace the _create event
    var orig_create = $.ui.dialog.prototype._create;
    $.ui.dialog.prototype._create = function(){
        orig_create.apply(this,arguments);
        var self = this;
        if(this.options.url!=''){
            self.element.load(self.options.url); // auto load the url selected
        };
    };

    $.widget( "ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
        refresh: function() {
            if(this.options.url!=''){
                this.element.load(this.options.url);
            }
        }
    });
```

Your final function would look like this:

```
// Note the "url" option.
function view_dialog() {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        url:'blah2.aspx',
        title: 'test' ,
        modal: 'true',
        width: '80%',
        height: '740',
        position: 'center',
        show: 'scale',
        hide: 'scale',
        cache: false });
}


// refresh:
$('#dialog').dialog("refresh");
```

You can see the final code in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WLg53/1/